# django.db.utils.IntegrityError when trying to delete duplicate images

Tags: sql, django, error-handling, exception, django-orm

I've got the following code to delete duplicate images from a perceptual hash I calculated.

```
images = Image.objects.all()
images_deleted = 0
for image in images:
    duplicates = Image.objects.filter(hash=image.hash).exclude(pk=image.pk).exclude(hash="ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff")
    for duplicate in duplicates:
        duplicate_tags = duplicate.tags.all()
        image.tags.add(*duplicate_tags)
        duplicate.delete()
        images_deleted+=1
        print(str(images_deleted))
```

running it I get the following exception:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table
>   "crawlers_image_tags" violates foreign key constraint
>   "crawlers_image_t_image_id_72a28d1d54e11b5f_fk_crawlers_image_id"
>
> DETAIL:  Key (image_id)=(5675) is not present in table
>   "crawlers_image".

can anyone shed some light on what exactly the problem is?

edit:

models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Image(models.Model):

    origins = (
        ('PX', 'Pexels'),
        ('MG', 'Magdeleine'),
        ('FC', 'FancyCrave'),
        ('SS', 'StockSnap'),
        ('PB', 'PixaBay'),
        ('TP', 'tookapic'),
        ('KP', 'kaboompics'),
        ('PJ', 'picjumbo'),
        ('LS', 'LibreShot')  
    )

    source_url = models.URLField(max_length=400)
    page_url = models.URLField(unique=True, max_length=400)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbs', null=True)
    origin = models.CharField(choices=origins, max_length=2)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.page_url

    def create_hash(self):
        thumbnail = Imagelib.open(self.thumbnail.path)
        thumbnail = thumbnail.convert('RGB')
        self.hash = blockhash(thumbnail, 24)
        self.save(update_fields=["hash"])

    def create_thumbnail(self, image_url):
        if not self.thumbnail:
            if  not image_url:
                image_url = self.source_url
            headers = {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36',
            }
            for i in range(5):
                r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True, headers=headers)
                if r.status_code != 200 and r.status_code!= 304:
                    print("error loading image url status code: {}".format(r.status_code))
                    time.sleep(2)
                else:
                    break

            if r.status_code != 200 and r.status_code!= 304:
                    print("giving up on this image, final status code: {}".format(r.status_code))
                    return False

            # Create the thumbnail of dimension size
            size = 500, 500
            img = Imagelib.open(r.raw)
            thumb = ImageOps.fit(img, size, Imagelib.ANTIALIAS)

            # Get the image name from the url
            img_name = os.path.basename(image_url.split('?', 1)[0])


            file_path = os.path.join(djangoSettings.MEDIA_ROOT, "thumb" + img_name)
            thumb.save(file_path, 'JPEG')

            # Save the thumbnail in the media directory, prepend thumb
            self.thumbnail.save(
                img_name,
                File(open(file_path, 'rb')))

            os.remove(file_path)
            return True
```

Comment: Can you show your models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine your code step by step.

Say, you have 3 images in your database (for simplicity i've skipped irrelevant fields):

```
Image(pk=1, hash="d2ffacb...e3')
Image(pk=2, hash="afcbdee...77')
Image(pk=3, hash="d2ffacb...e3')
```

As we can see, first and third image have exact same hash. Let's assume all your images have some tags. Now back to your code. Lets check what will happen in first iteration:

1. all images with same hash will be fetched from database, this will be only image `pk=3`
2. Iterating through that images will copy all your tags from that duplicates to original one. There is nothing wrong.
3. iterating through that images will also remove them.

So after first iteration, image with `pk=3` doesn't exist anymore.

Next iteration, image `pk=2`. Nothing will happen because there are no duplicates.

Next iteration, image `pk=3`.

1. all images with same hash will be fetched from database, this will be only image `pk=1`
2. Iterating through that images will copy all your tags from that duplicates to original one. But wait... there is no image `pk=3` in database, we can't assign any tags to it. And that will throw your `IntegrityError`.

To avoid that, you should simply fetch from database only original ones in outer for loop. To do that, you can do:

```
images = Image.objects.distinct('hash')
```

You can also add some ordering here, so there always will be fetched for example image with lower ID as original one:

```
images = Image.objects.order_by('id').distinct('hash')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is to do with the evaluation strategy of the queryset.

`Image.objects.all()` returns a thunk - that is, a sort of promise of an iterable sequence of images. The SQL query is not executed at this stage.

When you start iterating over it - `for image in images` - the SQL query is evaluated. You now have a list of image objects in memory.

Now, say you have four images in the database - ids 0, 1, 2, and 3. 0 and 3 are duplicates. The first image is processed, turning up 3 as a duplicate. You delete 3. *Image 3 is still in the `images` iterator*, however. When you get there, you're going to try to add tags from image 0 to image 3's tags collection. This will trigger the integrity error, since image 3 has already been deleted.

The simple fix is to keep an accumulator of images to be deleted, and do them all at the end.

```
images = Image.objects.all()
images_to_delete = []
for image in images:
    if image.pk in images_to_delete:
        pass
    else:
        duplicates = Image.objects.filter(hash=image.hash).exclude(pk=image.pk).exclude(hash="ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff")
        for duplicate in duplicates:
            duplicate_tags = duplicate.tags.all()
            image.tags.add(*duplicate_tags)
            images_to_delete.append(duplicate.pk)
            print(len(images_to_delete))

for pk in images_to_delete:
    Image.objects.get(pk=pk).delete()
```

**EDIT:** corrected proximate cause of the error, as pointed out by GwynBleidD.